# Hi team , i got a requirement where I need to check the checkboxes based on given input IDs in datatable buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

i got a requirement where I need to check the checkboxes based on given input IDs. Using a datatable button i have given the input ids for which i need the checkboxes to be checked. I am able to check the checkboxes of given input values. Here only td value is marked as checked but tr values does not have any selected class in it. Due to that when I am trying to fetch the selected rows , i didn't get any rows from the table even if the check boxes are checked. So my question is how will I add selected class in tr when I am constructing datatable:

```
Its quite a large chunk of code , cant do it . So basically i need to make a row as selected by default based on some column value.  
                                                 
function initDataTable(){
vm.List = [{"status":"UnAssigned","id":972139,"selectedValue":true},{"status":"Assigned","id":971109,"selectedValue":true}];
if(vm.dataTableInstance == null){
vm.dataTableInstance = $('.datatable-basic').DataTable({
data : vm.List,
columns : [
{data : 'selectedValue', orderable: false,
 className: 'select-checkbox',
targets: 0, render : function(data, type, row){
if(data === true){                                       
     $(this).closest('tr').addClass('selected');
    }
return '<span>&nbsp;</span>';
                            }},
                       { data: 'keycat.mg', title : 'MG', width : '5%' }],
        });
        $('.dataTables_filter input[type=search]').attr('placeholder','Type to filter...');
    } else {
        vm.dataTableInstance.clear();
        vm.dataTableInstance.rows.add(vm.workItemsList);
        vm.dataTableInstance.columns.adjust().draw();
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: You forgot the `"` around class name list

Comment: Hey Anton. I guess that's not required when we are using render function it will take the class name as select checkbox in <td> but I need to add selected element based on selectedValue which you see in data element.

Comment: Can you create Code snippet or jsfiddle to show us your problem?

Comment: Its quite a large chunk of code , cant do it instead of that I will update the main code

Comment: It is hard to understand what you are trying to achieve, that's why I ask for the code. In developer's world the code itself is more explanatory than the words. But in your case, you should describe the problem more detail: what you have (HTML, JS), the result you want to get (HTML, JS), what have you tried so far (HTML, JS).

Comment: Of course your code can be simplified and all strings replaced with "hello world" - only the HTML structure is interesting

Comment: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ryan279/15bfraey/12/) . but its not showing any datatable in my local workspace its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is how will I add selected class in tr when I am constructing datatable

Oh, now you have jsFiddle, so things getting more easy.

Add this magic to your DataTable parameters:

```
createdRow(row, data, index) {
  if (data.selectedValue) {
    $(row).addClass("selected-row");
  }
}
```

Here is working [jsFiddle with this example](https://jsfiddle.net/kjm6xuaq/) (note: I did not changed your other code).

Comment: Thanks a lot Anton for such a valuable information. Really appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi Anton, one more question . Now its getting selected based on values but when I am trying to fetch the default selected row then its not passing any row data . I have updated the code, can you please suggest something on that as well. [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ryan279/h6xvsoqk/15/)

Comment: How do you try to fetch the default selected row? Which part of your code do this?

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle , there is a method assignUser() which will fetch the rows having selected as class element.

Comment: Hi Anton, resolved the issue. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Ryan Well, ok. If it really helps, then mark the answer as "accepted".